# How to center those images in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

Hey there stackoverflow

I am trying to center those images. I tried everything I found about vertical centering in bootstrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/tLd85urn/41/

Here you can see my sourcecode. If I remove the lines on "div" and "html" in the CSS stylesheet (height: 100%;), the images seems centered, but the whole page is stacked together. How can I center those images, and keep the "fullscreen" layout?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* If I remove this line, it works, but its no more fullscreen */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  /* If I remove this line, it works, but its no more fullscreen */
  /*width: 100%; */
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 10% !important;
}

.content {
  height: 80% !important;
}

.footer {
  height: 10% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row header text-center align-items-center align-middle">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-2</div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-lg-8</div>
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row content text-center align-items-center align-middle">
    <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-1</div>
    <div class="align-items-center align-middle col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-10" style="background-color:blue;">.col-lg-10<img src="test2.png" class="align-items-center align-middle img-fluid rounded mx-auto" alt="Responsive image"><img src="test2.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto" alt="Responsive image"><img src="test2.png" class="img-fluid mx-auto" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer text-center">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-2</div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-lg-8</div>
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the end it should look like this:
[image]

Thanks for your help and greetings,

Tine

Comment: In attached fiddle, images doesn't shows up

Comment: please upload images in attached JsFiddle so that ii can answer your desire question

Comment: Image is now added in the fiddle and how it should look is also in the post attached. Thanks for every help!

Comment: @TineWittler Added an answer, please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `d-flex justify-content-center` to the container having 3 images

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* If I remove this line, it works, but its no more fullscreen */
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 100%; */
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 10% !important;
}

.content {
  height: 80% !important;
}

.footer {
  height: 10% !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row header text-center align-items-center align-middle">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-2</div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-lg-8</div>
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row content text-center align-items-center align-middle">
    <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-1</div>
    <div class="align-items-center align-middle col-xl-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-10 d-flex justify-content-center" style="background-color:blue;">.col-lg-10<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1644a81b938%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1644a81b938%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2274.09375%22%20y%3D%22104.6546875%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
        class="align-items-center align-middle img-fluid rounded mx-auto" alt="Responsive image"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1644a81b938%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1644a81b938%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2274.09375%22%20y%3D%22104.6546875%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
        class="img-fluid mx-auto" alt="Responsive image"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1644a81b938%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1644a81b938%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2274.09375%22%20y%3D%22104.6546875%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
        class="img-fluid mx-auto" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer text-center">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-2</div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-lg-8</div>
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-2<img src="test3.png" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto" alt="Responsive image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid" style=background-color:lavender>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col">
      image1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    image2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    image3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Hey are u seeing something like this ?? this is what i came appropriate for your query
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand how Bootstrap's grid system works. You need to be clear on one breakpoint after which content can stack one below the other. Here's a modification to your code which may help you understand better:

Bootstrap classes (col-md-4, lg-8 etc) will automatically help you do the resizing, to center the image, use the following CSS rules:

CSS

```
img{
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

This will ensure that your image takes up the full width of the div. Check the fiddle for the full code.

Here is [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/tLd85urn/27/) to the updated fiddle.

Comment: I don't agree with the property width:100%. What if the container is bigger than the image itself?